# Netatalk users can't read World/Other readable files

Tags: permissions, osx, file-server

I'm using Netatalk to share documents with several Mac machines. Regardless of what permissions I'm using for the file (typically 775 for folders and 664 for files) they can't be read by users in the Other/World group.

The mac sees the correct permission when I view it under "Get Info" but still cannot open a file even with 777 permissions.

Not all files are like this, only a limited few in some limited folders.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the .AppleDouble files are at fault. When I `ls -la` and look at my .AppleDouble file in the directory in question:

```
drwxrwxrw-    2 admin admin    28672 May  5 15:13 .AppleDouble
```

The issue is the executable bit under the other permissions. Netatalk users need the execute bit set to use the files inside the folder. This is why the group and owner has no problems getting inside and using all files but the world user on the AFP share couldn't do so.

Source: https://sourceforge.net/p/netatalk/mailman/message/9128281/